# Understanding concepts of timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a code to print 5 consecutive date and time each having 2 seconds of difference. Given below is the python code.

```
import datetime
import time
lt = []
for i in range(5):
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   after = (now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=2))
   lt.append(after)

for i in lt:
   print(i)
```

it instead resulted in  completely different output as provided below.

```
2018-09-29 18:05:50.791096
2018-09-29 18:05:50.791096
2018-09-29 18:05:50.791096
2018-09-29 18:05:50.791096
2018-09-29 18:05:50.791096
2018-09-29 18:08:56.935234
2018-09-29 18:08:56.935234
2018-09-29 18:08:56.935234
2018-09-29 18:08:56.935234
2018-09-29 18:08:56.935234
```

Although, I got the correct intended result using

```
time.sleep(2)
```

But what actually is wrong in the above provided code that output is coming out to be different.

Comment: Think about it... is your computer so slow that it takes 2 seconds to complete an iteration of your `for i in range(5):` loop?

Comment: Use `.timedelta(seconds=i * 2)`